# Encoding issue with uploaded text file in PHP

Tags: php

When uploading a text file and read data to save in database in PHP. It appends `\0` with every character when using `addslashes` like this:

```
$city=trim(addslashes($row[7]));
```

Comment: You should not be using `addslashes` for anything, really.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multibyte characters in your file `addslashes` will just corrupt your encoding.

If you want to escape string before inserting it into DB use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `PDO` or any other appropriate library.